# bootstrap 2 grid displaying not behaving as expected (span12...)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I copy pasted the sample code from bootstrap site and do not get the expected result

Adapted from here:
view-source:http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms

```
My code is:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
..................
</head>

<body>

<form class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 15px;">
    <div class="controls ">
        <input class="span12" type="text" placeholder=".span12">
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row span12">
        <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4"> 
        <input class="span8" type="text" placeholder=".span8">
    </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row span12">
        <input class="span9" type="text" placeholder=".span9"> 
        <input class="span3" type="text" placeholder=".span3">
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row span12">
        <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6"> 
        <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6">
    </div>
</form>
...

</body>
</html>
```

It displayed as per attached screenshot.

[image]

There are 3 things that are not as expected:
- The grid displays on half screen although I set span12 class.
- What should be the 3rd line has been concatenated after the 2nd line
- The second line's starting position is a bit on the right of the 1st line starting position

Any help appreciated to get this clarified.

I have to stick to bootstrap2 by the way, I cannot use bootstrap3 for this project.

Comment: it looks like you haven't included the bootstrap css in html file have you.?

Comment: Yes they are included into the headers.

Comment: can you just make js.fiddle of this.?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7L6nLt42/

Comment: Simply put, you aren't using the grid correctly. You don't have any row elements, and your columns are inconsistent. I suggest building your grid first, then adding the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format to solve all of the 3 problems was actually :

```
<form class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 15px;">
    <div class="controls  ">
        <input class="span12" type="text" placeholder=".span12">
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row ">
        <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4"> 
        <input class="span8" type="text" placeholder=".span8">
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row ">
        <input class="span9" type="text" placeholder=".span9"> 
        <input class="span3" type="text" placeholder=".span3">
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row ">
        <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6"> 
        <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6">
    </div>
</form>
```

It looks the span12 tag inside the divs of line2, 3 and 4 was causing the mess.
Thx all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The code</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <body>
        <form class="bs-docs-example" style="padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 15px;">
            <div class="controls ">
                <input class="span12" type="text" placeholder=".span12">
            </div>
            <div class="controls controls-row span12">
                <input class="span4" type="text" placeholder=".span4"> 
                <input class="span8" type="text" placeholder=".span8">
            </div>
            <div class="controls controls-row span12">
                <input class="span9" type="text" placeholder=".span9"> 
                <input class="span3" type="text" placeholder=".span3">
            </div>
            <div class="controls controls-row span12">
                <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6"> 
                <input class="span6" type="text" placeholder=".span6">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You have an error above the 3rd div.span12

Comment: I get exactly the same result. However, I can see that the bs-docs-example is not included in any of the 4 boostrap 2 css files.

Comment: With the code snippet, indeed the 3rd line is not concatenated to the 2nd one.
But it is if I copy paste the code in an html form with BS2 includes.
Can it be because bs-docs-example is not included in any of the 4 css files downloaded with BS2 package??

Comment: This may well be from the version of BS

Comment: <link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: same result if I add this link in headers.